# escape R"()" in a raw string in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, rawstring

```
  string raw_str = R"(R"(foo)")";
```

If I have `R"()"` inside a raw string, and that causes the parser to confuse. (ie., it thought the left most `)"` was the end of the raw string.

How do I escape this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include )" in raw string literal without terminating said literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308088/include-in-raw-string-literal-without-terminating-said-literal)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The format for the [raw-string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)[[2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.string#nt:raw-string)] is: `R"delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"`

so you can use a different *delimiter* that is not in the string like:

```
string raw_str = R"~(R"(foo)")~";
```

Answer (score 13):

The raw string will terminate after the first `)"` it sees. You can change the delimiter to `***` for example:

```
string raw_str = R"***(R"(foo)")***";
```